# Why is this proof about the alternating harmonic series not enough?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I just got my homework back and I don't really know why my proof wasn't enough, it's about rearranging the alternating harmonic series.

$(a_k)_{a \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence with $a_k= (-1)^k/k$. $g_k =2k$ and $u_k=2k-1$, define a new sequence $(b_k)_{b \in \mathbb{N}}$: $a_{u_1}, a_{g_1}, a_{g_2}; a_{u_2}, a_{g_3}, a_{g_4};...$.

We already know that the limit  $a:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ exists. Show that  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ converges as well and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k=\frac{1}{2}a$.

---

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k=-1 + \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}-...$

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k=-1 + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{12}-...$

$=(-1 + \frac{1}{2}) +\frac{1}{4}+(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6})+\frac{1}{8}+(-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{10})+\frac{1}{12}-...$

$= \frac{1}{2}(-1 + \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-...)=\frac{1}{2}a$

I got 2/3 points for this and he said that I can't use $...$ notation here. But I don't understand why, I did some other proofs with $exp$ $sin$ and $cos$ and it was fine there. For example:

Show that $cos(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}...$.

$cos(z) = \frac{1}{2}(exp(iz)+exp(-iz))=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(iz)^{k}}{(2k)!}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-iz)^{k}}{(2k)!}$

$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{iz}{2}-\frac{z^2}{2(2!)}-\frac{iz^3}{2(3!)}+\frac{z^4}{2(4!)}+...$

$+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{iz}{2}-\frac{z^2}{2(2!)}+\frac{iz^3}{2(3!)}+\frac{z^4}{2(4!)}-...$

$=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-...$

I got 2/2 points for this, why is using $...$ fine here and not in the other exercise?
When am I allowed to use $...$ notation and when do I have to use $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty$?

Comment: Have you asked your teacher/professor?

Comment: Yea but I didn't really understand his answer tbh, that's why I'm asking it here again

Comment: Perhaps in the second exercise it is more obvious that the pattern of cancellation will continue. In the first exercise it may be less obvious. Also, you have to be very careful in rearranging or regrouping terms in a series that does not converge absolutely (as you see, it can change the value of the final sum), so your professor may want you to be more rigorous for that reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did *not* prove that your series converges. All that you proved was that *if* it converges, then its sum is half the sum of the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

When putting those brackets you unjustifiably rearrange the order of the terms in infinitely many places. In the second example it's okay because the series converge absolutely.